# How to horizontally centre a non-fixed width div?

Tags: css, html

OK, I have a div that is in the centred:

```
<div id="spry">
<p> hello there asdsdfasd  adsfasdf aasdfasfd </p>
</div>
```

Uses this CSS:

```
#spry {
background-color: red; 
display: block; 
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto; 
width: 400px; 
}
```

But I want to have the div not a fixed width. I figured I could just change `width: 400px`;
to `width: auto;`

But if you do that it just expands to the whole width.

Comment: You can change it's display value to `inline-block` and then use `text-align: center;` on its parent container.

Comment: Perfect answer. Post it as one!

Comment: I just don't like doing that because it's not very semantic.  Im centring a div, not text.

Comment: Just because an element is within the [inline formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-formatting) does *not* mean it has to be text - the `inline-block` display value exists for doing things just like this - hence the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the display value to `inline-block` and then use `text-align: center;` on its parent container (though since it doesn't have one I just used the `<body>` as an example):

```
body {
    text-align: center; 
}

#spry {
    background-color: red; 
    display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3DBha/1/

Comment: Best choice, but I saw another option somewhere on SO, had been used `absolute`/`relative` position types and played with `left`/`right` properties. I'll post the link if I found it.

Comment: This doesn't work if the user wants a fixed or max-width of 400px.. otherwise it's good.

Comment: Judging by the title I don't think that's what he's after - and [it does work](http://jsfiddle.net/3DBha/2/) if you have a fixed width

Answer (score 1):

You can use `max-width` - This essentially says don't be anymore than 400pixels but you can be smaller. Try resizing the window.

This is a good option if you **do not want** a fixed width. Alternatively you could try a percentage, then just use `max-width` to define a maximum width that you desire.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Pr4gd/3/)

You can see the width displayed as you resize just to demonstrate

Answer (score -1):

try `margin:0 auto;` see what happens

Comment: That's an invalid syntax.